# Creating universal Cocoapods framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have project with 10+ targets in Xcode. I am using cocoapods to provide me some frameworks.
But Pod projects starting to grow (many files)
It is possible somehow configure Pod file to create one universal configuration, which is imported to other projects? Something like abstract target?
I don't need for each target create new pod framework, because all my targets using same pods.

Thanks for suggestion.

Something like this:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

custom config 'Pods-framewrks' do
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'Alamofire'
end

project = Xcodeproj::Project.open “./MyProject.xcodeproj"

project.targets.each do |t|
 target t.name do
   import framework Pods  // ???
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put `pod 'Alamofire'` outside of any specific target, then it will be included in all targets.

For example:

```rb
platform :ios, '11.0'

pod 'Alamofire'

target 'FirstTarget' do
end

target 'SecondTarget' do
  pod 'SwifterSwift'
end
```

Comment: But this will create Pod_FirstTarget.framework and Pod_SecondTarget framweworks.
I want to avoid that and have only Pod.framework linked to both of them.

Comment: Ah, I see. Why do you want to avoid these frameworks?

Comment: I have many apps (I want reduce number of files and size o project)
And I found that pods have problems with some targets names, which are using some local diacritic.

Comment: I tried to replace Pods with Carthage recently, but some frameworks, which I am using, not supporting it. :-(

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-binary (never tried it myself)